# MeanIO - Getting blank screen when running app

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, mongodb, mean

so I've been trying to setup MeanIO pretty much the whole afternoon and I think I fixed all packages and I'm no longer getting any errors however when I enter gulp, it says app is uploaded on port 3000 so when I go to localhost:3000 I get a blank white screen and in the console I get numerous identical lines , the last couple ones are:

```
GET /users/services/meanUser.js?v=c1798571fe1c2940e66122b372f194a1 304 - - 16.333 ms
GET /i18n/controllers/i18n.js?v=ae68933b2eb5958c3681ca6d0c5900f9 304 - - 4.747 ms
GET /i18n/routes/i18n.js?v=87cf316f40734f4de4ac7b8c8de8b743 304 - - 5.529 ms
GET /i18n/services/i18n.js?v=a5648d710a401062a9f2a45879229962 304 - - 9.927 ms
GET /mail-templates/controllers/mailTemplates.js?v=6240dee4df92ffa0debfa0cb11857469 304 - - 8.879 ms
GET /mail-templates/routes/mailTemplates.js?v=d307bcd2f307eb8faecd53536b46de6a 304 - - 9.891 ms
GET /mail-templates/services/mailTemplates.js?v=cf42aa9a61aaee980415b067f8db269f 304 - - 10.107 ms
GET /theme/controllers/theme.js?v=178c0725093af215ec559f8087f4a0c1 304 - - 12.193 ms
GET /theme/routes/theme.js?v=9f13d469eb9a1dbc569f6c923344e7b9 304 - - 1.697 ms
GET /theme/services/theme.js?v=ebcfe06850666ec1092d6fa2a6468409 304 - - 6.329 ms
GET /_getModules 304 - - 2.347 ms
GET /favicon.ico 200 - - 0.933 ms
```

Any idea what might be the reason? Sorry if question is noob/vague, but I have been out of the web dev game for a while so I'm a newbie ... will provide extra info if necessary.

Thank you!

UPDATE:

I think the problem might be that I get errors when I try to run `sudo npm install -g` , these are the errors:

```
npm ERR! addLocal Could not install /usr/local/lib/node_modules/mean/node_modules/meanio/lib/core_modules/server
npm ERR! Linux 3.16.0-53-generic
npm ERR! argv "node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/mean/node_modules/.bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! node v0.10.26
npm ERR! npm  v2.13.5

npm ERR! No version provided in package.json
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /usr/local/lib/node_modules/mean/node_modules/meanio/lib/core_modules/server/npm-debug.log
/usr/local/lib
└── (empty)
```

Comment: can you show your package.json??

Comment: @KethaKavya yeah sure, there it is - http://pastebin.com/HKpBFhZ8 | forgot to add in my question - I'm running it on Ubuntu and I've granted my user with full permissions over the project folder